# UITableViewCell background selection state flips before gesture ends

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

**CODE**

I have some code that adds a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` gesture recognizer called `_recognizer` to a subclass of a `UITableViewCell` called `cell`:

```
...
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *_recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellLongPressRecognized:)];
_recognizer.allowableMovement = 20;
_recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
[[cell contentView] addGestureRecognizer:_recognizer];
[_recognizer release];
...
```

The `-cellLongPressRecognized:` selector simply logs when the gesture ends:

```
- (void) cellLongPressRecognized:(id)_sender {
    if (((UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)_sender).state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        ALog(@"[MyViewController] -cellLongPressRecognized: gesture ended...");
}
```

My console shows one log message when I tap, hold and release a cell:

```
[MyViewController] -cellLongPressRecognized: gesture ended...
```

So far, so good.

**ISSUE**

The issue is that the table cell's background stays selected only as long as 1.0 second, the `_recognizer.minimumPressDuration` property.

If I hold my finger on the device any longer than 1.0 second, the cell's background flips back from the `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` selection style to its usual, opaque, non-selected background.

To make sure only gesture-specific code is involved with this issue, I have disabled `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` while testing.

**QUESTION**

How do I keep the background selected indefinitely, flipped back only when the "long press" gesture ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed my test condition from `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` to `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and the gesture is timed with the cell selection state change:

```
- (void) cellLongPressRecognized:(id)_sender {
    if (((UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)_sender).state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        ALog(@"[MyViewController] -cellLongPressRecognized: gesture began...");
}
```

Seems counterintuitive naming the event this way, but that seems to work.